# Slight Emergency : Internet Explorer not Reading CSS?

Tags: html, css, video

Luanched a site today (perhaps prematurey, but not my call), and we are having issues with internet explorer on the following page:

http://702wedding.com/live/

Works Fine in Every Browser I have Checked. Except IE. Looks like its not reading the style sheet, but not sure.

A fix would be great whenever possible.

Always appreciate the help people have.

Comment: Which version of IE, on what OS? And, incidentally, there's a [few validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://702wedding.com/live/&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: Could also be the way it has been built. There are some pretty non-standard techniques used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very difficult to do any tests, because of the JS/AJAX/iframe/it's complicated/it's complicated (encore).

You could try loading the relevant CSS file inside your main page:

```
<!-- CSS Links -->
<link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/colorbox.css" />

<!-- add this -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/video-nav.css" />
```

Good luck!

Comment: I'm amazed that was all it took. What a guess!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the media attribute in your  to screen,all. E.g.

```
<link href="../css/main.css" media="screen,all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link type="text/css" media="screen,all" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/colorbox.css" />
```

Any specific version of IE, or just all of 'em?